# Dynamic loading html

Tags: html, node.js, json, express, handlebars.js

I‘m using node.js, express and handlebars.

Currently I‘m passing json via res.render() to hbs. In the hbs I‘m using {{#each dataJson}} to iterate over it and list the contents of my json. Now... what if my json had like a million entries? It would take forever to load my page then, right?

Now to my Question:
How do I load that dynamic? I want the page to load the html from the json while showing what‘s already loaded.

Sorry for my bad english. It‘s not my native language.

Best regards

Naggelus

Comment: A typical solution for this would be to have the Express server deliver a page that is mostly empty, i.e. not displaying the data yet, then load the data on the client side using Ajax calls. It's hard to provide a proper answer, since IMO your question is not a good fit for this platform, which is mostly for specific questions with code examples.

Comment: Yeah. I‘m currently on my phone and can‘t really provide any code right now. I‘ll see if I can add some later. Thank you for the suggestion with ajax though.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a lazy loading mechanism. 
Instead of loading all the million records on the initial load, you would need to send it in chunks. Based on the view port, the records can be decided and load the first page. When the user goes over those records, you need send another API request to fetch the next chunk and so on.
This would load only the necessary records to the UI.